# WordPress Custom Search Form (WooCommerce Product Category)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Can anybody help?

Why is this not working?

```
<form role="search" method="get" action="/">
    <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search">
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product">
  <input type="hidden" value="product_cat" name="the-journal-of-stained-glass" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

It 'should' be filtering out search results that are only in the product category specified, but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you have mistaken in the code in the place of name in the input field you have provided value of the category and in the place of value you provided name. Please try as following.

```
<form role="search" method="get" action="/">
    <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search">
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product">
  <input type="hidden" name="product_cat" value="the-journal-of-stained-glass" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Please add this following in your functions.php in that please replace the taxonomy with your taxonomy

```
function wc_hide_selected_terms( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ) {
    $new_terms = array();
    if ( in_array( 'product_cat', $taxonomies ) && !is_admin() && is_shop() ) {
        foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
              if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, array( 'uncategorized' ) ) ) {
                $new_terms[] = $term;
              }
        }
        $terms = $new_terms;
    }
    return $terms;
}
add_filter( 'get_terms', 'wc_hide_selected_terms', 10, 3 );

function advanced_search_query($query) {

        if($query->is_search()) {
            // category terms search.
            if (isset($_GET['product_cat']) && !empty($_GET['product_cat'])) {
                $query->set('tax_query', array(array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $_GET['product_cat']) 
                ));
            }    
        }
        return $query;
    }
    add_action('pre_get_posts', 'advanced_search_query', 1000);
```

Comment: Hi James, thanks for that, but unfortunately that hasn't helped in fixing the problem.

Comment: Did you add coding in functions.php file in your theme ?

Comment: Any specific coding? I have nothing relating to the search function in there.

Comment: I have added the code for functions.php also in that please replace your taxonomy with the current taxonomy.

Comment: Thanks, but that gives me the following error

Warning:  mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /homepages/11/d741879078/htdocs/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1102

Comment: OK, the error was my mistake, but the code provided hasn't gotten me any closer I'm afraid. It is still outputting various product_cats in the results.

Comment: http://bsmgpdev.org.uk/?s=glass&post_type=product&product_cat=the-journal-of-stained-glass

Just by hovering over the read more, you can see these are entries from multiple product categories.

Comment: Did you changed this in ***  Your Taxonomy name ***  functions.php ?

Comment: Yes, I did. There's an error in that code somewhere as I'm now getting this;

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')' in /homepages/11/d741879078/htdocs/wp-content/themes/bsmgp/functions.php on line 496

Comment: Line 496 is this; ));

I have to remove the code for now as I need to leave the office for a short while. Happy to pay if this can be fixed...

Comment: I got it please take it out